# Excel VBA replacing question mark in a string

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string `ShrtDesc` as follows:

```
? HYPOALLERGENIdisorders. SET OF 3. 
? SAVE MONEY &
```

I am trying the following:

```
ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, "?", "")
ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, "~?", "")
ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, Chr(63), "")
ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, ChrW(63), "")
```

But I am unable to replace the question mark. I am not sure what else to try.

Edit:
I got it by scraping an Amazon page.

```
Debug.Print Asc(Left(ShrtDesc, 1))
63

Debug.Print VarType(ShrtDesc)
 8
```

Edit 2:
I am using the following code:

```
Sub testSub()
    Dim pKey As String
    pKey = "B07R212XKH"
    Dim AmazonUrl As String
    AmazonUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=" & Trim(pKey)
    
    Dim Msxml, Msxml2, Doc, Doc2 As Object
    Set Msxml = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp")
    Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set Msxml2 = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp")
    Set Doc2 = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Msxml.Open "GET", AmazonUrl, False
    Msxml.Send ""
    Doc.body.innerhtml = Msxml.ResponseText
    
    Dim AllProducts, Product As Object
    Dim ProductUrl, ShrtDesc As String
    
    Set AllProducts = Doc.getelementsbytagname("h2")
    For Each Product In AllProducts
        ProductUrl = Product.getelementsbytagname("a").Item(0).href
        ProductUrl = Replace(ProductUrl, "about:/", "https://www.amazon.com/")
        
        Msxml2.Open "GET", ProductUrl, False
        Msxml2.Send ""
        Doc2.body.innerhtml = Msxml2.ResponseText
        ShrtDesc = Doc2.getelementbyid("featurebullets_feature_div").innertext
        ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, "?", "")
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you defining the string? First option works for me

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Can you confirm that it is an actual question mark though? Check `Debug.Print Asc(Left(ShrtDesc, 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the check. Can you also check `Debug.Print VarType(ShrtDesc)` and make sure it returns `8`?

Comment: Yes vartype is 8 also

Comment: Do you have a larger section of your code, as of right now, there is no way of replicating your issue. Try to be as complete as possible but ditch all the code that is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: From the original source where the "question mark" comes, copy that and paste the value into your vba code `Replace` statement. Sometimes that solves it because the character is actually an usual character that is not what we think it is. Or, if it is always in first spot, use `ShrtDesc = Mid(ShrtDesc,2,Len(ShrtDesc))`

Comment: You should be able to replicate the issue now hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so as per @ScottHoltzman; The question mark can be a placeholder for text not displayed correctly by Excel. So let's take a look at the text as is at the [source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R212XKH):

[image]

Right, that's not an question mark indeed, but instead its the [black heart suit](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%E2%99%A5&preview=entity). The unicode for that character would be: "U+2665" so you can now use:

```
ShrtDesc = Replace(ShrtDesc, ChrW(&H2665), "")
```